# Optimal probability measure

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory

Let $A$ be a finite set and let $\Bbb P$ be a probability measure on $A^{\Bbb N_0}$. Further, let $x_i:A^{\Bbb N_0}\to A$ be projection maps, so that $(x_i)_{i=0}^\infty$ can be treated as a stochastic process. Suppose that for some integer number $m\geq 1$ the measure $\Bbb P$ satisfies the following condition:
$$
  (x_i,\dots,x_{i+m})_*\Bbb P = (x_0,\dots,x_m)_*\Bbb P\quad \forall i\in \Bbb N,\tag{1}
$$ 
that is any sequence of the length $m+1$ has equal probability of appearance anywhere along the trajectory of the process. For example, $\Bbb P$ is shift-invariant (stationary) if and only if it satisfies $(1)$ **for any** choice of $m$. In my case, the number $m$ is fixed though, so $\Bbb P$ does not have to be a stationary measure.

Let us denote $\Bbb P^m := (x_0,\dots,x_m)_*\Bbb P$ to be a measure on $A^{m+1}$, and let $F:A^{m+1}\to\Bbb R$ be some arbitrary function. Suppose, I need to maximize
$$
  \Bbb P^m[F]:=\sum_{s\in A^{m+1}}F(s)\cdot\Bbb P^m(\{s\}) \tag{2}.
$$
where the optimization is done over all possible measures $\Bbb P$ that satisfy $(1)$. Have such problem been already studied, perhaps the solution is already known?

Comment: what are you trying to maximise over? The way I read your description everything in (2) is fixed.

Comment: @Tim: I am maximizing $(2)$ over all possible measures $\Bbb P$ that satisfy $(1)$. An alternative way of thinking about it is that I am maximizing $(2)$ over set of all possible measures $\Bbb P^m$  (which is a subset of some finite-dimensional space) that are extendable to some $\Bbb P$ that satisfies $(1)$.

Comment: On a second reading that's clear from your question. My mistake.  Can you see why it's enough to maximise $F$ over repeating sequences (period $m$) shifted uniformly?

Comment: @Tim: ok, edited to make it more clear. W.r.t. your question - do you mean the Dirak measure over some $m$-periodic sequence? Then I indeed can't see why that would be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

For a finite sequence $Y= (y_0,\dots,y_m)$ let $\left <Y\right>\subset A^{m+1}$ be the set of sequences 
$$\left<Y\right> = \{ (y_i, y_{i+1 \mod (m+1)}, \dots y_{i+1 \mod (m+1)}) :  0 \leq i \leq m \}$$
be the set of shifts of $Y$.

Now let $$\mathscr F = \left\{\left<Y\right> : Y\in A^{m+1}\right\}$$
be the shift invariant $\sigma$-algebra on $A^{m+1}$.  As $\mathscr F$ is a partition $\sigma$-algebra we have
$$\mathbb P^m\left[F \left| \mathscr F\right.\right](Y) = \frac 1{m+1} \sum_{\hat Y\in\left<Y\right>} F(\hat Y).$$

Therefore if $\bar Y$ is such that 
$\sum_{\hat Y\in\left<\bar Y\right>} F(\hat Y)\geq\sum_{\hat Y\in\left< Y\right>} F(\hat Y)$ for every $Y\in A^{m+1}$ we have

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\mathbb P^m\left[F \right] &= \int_{A^{m+1}}  \mathbb P^m\left[F \left| \mathscr F\right.\right](X) d \mathbb P^m(X) \\
&\leq \int_{A^{m+1}}  \mathbb P^m\left[F \left| \mathscr F\right.\right](\bar Y) d \mathbb P^m(X) \\
&=\frac 1{m+1}\sum_{\hat Y\in\left<\bar Y\right>} F(\hat Y)
\end{array}$$

So  set $\mathbb P$ to be the measure constructed by choosing $(x_0,\dots,x_m)$ uniformly from $\left<\bar Y\right>$ and setting $x_k = x_{k \mod (m+1)}$ for $k> m$ then $\mathbb P$ is shift invariant by construction and 
$$\mathbb P^m\left[F \right] =\frac 1{m+1}\sum_{\hat Y\in\left<\bar Y\right>} F(\hat Y)$$
attains its maximal value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Some of the points are unclear there to me, though. First of all, let us use \hat in $\hat X = (\hat x_0,\dots,\hat x_m)$ and $X$ just for the generic element of $A^{m+1}$. How do you define $\mathscr F$, in terms of a fixed $\hat X$? Also, in the current version
$$
  \Bbb P^m[F(X)|\mathscr F](X)
$$
seems to be about a generic $X$, rather than about a fixed $\hat X$, right?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, I obviously wrote the first response too quickly.  Hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following counterexample.

Let $A=\{0,1\}$ and $m=2$.
Consider the optimization problem with
$$F(110) = F(100) = F(001) = F(011) = 1,\qquad F=0\; \text{otherwise}.
$$

This problem is solved by 
$$\mathbb{P}^m(110) = \mathbb{P}^m(100) = \mathbb{P}^m(001) = \mathbb{P}^m(011) = 1/4,
\qquad \mathbb{P}^m=0\; \text{otherwise}.$$
and the optimal value is $1$.

The stochastic process can be build by choosing with equal probability $1/4$ one of the
realizations

$(00110011\dots), (01100110\dots), (11001100\dots), (10011001\dots)$

Note that $\{(110),(100),(001),(011)\}$ is not a shift-invariant class and the average 
of the objective function is less than 1 for all the possible shift-invariant classes.

The problem in the proof (I guess) is assigning equal probability $\frac{1}{m+1}$ to all the elements
inside a shift-invariant class (it does not need to be the case).